# Error converting phone_number to integer: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: python, variables, agi

I'm trying to do the following:
The script takes a line from the file, splits it, and then the phone number should be set as a variable for the asterisk dialplan.

File line looks like:

```
Doe,John,Adam,123456789
```

But I get an error:

```
Error converting phone_number to integer: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

At the same time, as I understand it, the variable is set, because if I print it, it exists.

```
phone: 123456789
```

Tell me, please, what is the error?

```
with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
    i = 0  
    for line in file:
        
        parts = line.strip().split(',')

        # Ensure that there are enough parts in the line
        if len(parts) >= 4:
            surname, name, lastname, phone_number = parts[:4]

            # Check if phone_number is not empty before conversion
            if phone_number.strip():  # Check if the stripped value is not empty
                try:
                    phone_number = int(phone_number)
                    agi.set_variable('PHONE_NUMBER', f"{phone_number}")
                except ValueError as e:
                    print(f"Error converting phone_number to integer: {e}")
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"Error setting PHONE_NUMBER: {e}")
            else:
                print(f"Empty phone_number encountered on line {i + 1}, skipping...")
        else:
            print(f"Invalid line format on line {i + 1}: {line.strip()}")

        print(f"phone: {phone_number}")
```

---

Update1:

If I remove the conversion to integer, I get this error:

```
        COMMAND: SET VARIABLE "PHONE_NUMBER" "123456789"
    SET VARIABLE "PHONE_NUMBER" "123456789"
    
        RESULT_LINE:
    Error setting PHONE_NUMBER: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 
''
phone: 123456789
```

Updated code

```
with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        parts = line.strip().split(',')

        # Ensure that there are enough parts in the line
        if len(parts) >= 4:
            surname, name, lastname, phone_number = parts[:4]

            # Check if phone_number is not empty before conversion
            if phone_number.strip():  # Check if the stripped value is not empty
                try:
                    agi.set_variable('PHONE_NUMBER', phone_number.strip())
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"Error setting PHONE_NUMBER: {e}")
            else:
                print(f"Empty phone_number encountered on line {i + 1}, skipping...")
        else:
            print(f"Invalid line format on line {i + 1}: {line.strip()}")

        print(f"name: {phone_number}")
```

---

Update2
Code:

```
# Check if phone_number is not empty before conversion
            if len(phone_number) > 0:  # Check if the stripped value is not empty
                try:
                    agi.set_variable('PHONE_NUMBER', phone_number.strip())
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"Error setting PHONE_NUMBER: {e}")
            else:
                print(f"Empty phone_number encountered on line {i + 1}, skipping...")
        else:
            print(f"Invalid line format on line {i + 1}: {line.strip()}")
```

Error:

```
    COMMAND: SET VARIABLE "PHONE_NUMBER" "123456789"
SET VARIABLE "PHONE_NUMBER" "123456789"

    RESULT_LINE:
Error setting PHONE_NUMBER: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
name: 123456789
```

Comment: Note that phone numbers are not integers, and trying to convert them to integers is asking for trouble. Treat them as strings.

Comment: Phone numbers are best dealt with as strings.  They can contain punctuation like '-' and + .  Maybe '(' and ')' for some complicated systems which allow abbreviations. Also, phone numbers can, in general, be considerably long depending on the specific phone system.

Comment: What should i try?

Answer (score 0):

As I can see from your error message, that empty string is passed to your int() function.

Check your file and your code again.

[image: Picture of error message with highlights]

> phone_number.strip()

is being evaluated as True (May be due Python version).

Try to use ,

> len(phone_number) > 0

Comment: I added your recommendation, I get the same error as in the updated code 1

Comment: You are using **if phone_number.strip():** instead try to use **if len(phone_number) > 0:**

Comment: Added update 2 with your recommendations, getting an error